# how can i read html source code with line blank using content.match (google app script)

Tags: html, regex, google-apps-script, line

i want to read htmlsource and write price 
but there are some error

not to read htmlsource

how can i do?

### this is what i want to read data

```
<p class="lbl_ItemPriceSingleItem product-price">USD 425.00
                                        </p>
```

---

```
var spanclass = content.match(/<p class="lbl_ItemPriceSingleItem product-price"><\/p>/);

->        
var spanclass = content.match(/<p class="lbl_ItemPriceSingleItem product-price">    <br><\/p>/);


 p>/p>is far away. So I think  can't read html properly.
```

so i rewrite

but it also doesn't work properly.

```
  var spanclass = content.match(/<p class="lbl_ItemPriceSingleItem product-price"> <br><\/p>/);
```

Comment: Try `content.match(/<p class="lbl_ItemPriceSingleItem product-price">(.*)/);`

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [URLFetchApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) and then parse your result with regular expression matching.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can search a string for a match against regular expression using the built-in `string.match()` function:

```
var string = "some searchable string for RegEx";
string.match(/some search(.*)/);
```

The return value of `string.match()` is an array that contains the matches in the string, with one array item for each match. If no matches are found, it will return `null`. In the above case, `string.match()` will return:

```
[some searchable string for RegEx,  able string for RegEx]
```

The `(.*)` in the regular expression finds any character sequence so can be used in between the HTML tags:

```
var content = '<p class="lbl_ItemPriceSingleItem product-price">USD 425.00\
                                        </p>';  
var spanclass = content.match(/<p class="lbl_ItemPriceSingleItem product-price">(.*)<\/p>/);
```

In order to get only the text embedded in the `<p>` tags.